# Compute the difference between a row value and the rest in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 4],
    [4, 6],
    [8, 2],
    [0, 8]
], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

How can I compute the difference between the first row vs the rest in a column like this:

```py
df['operation_on_a'] = pd.DataFrame([
    ['1-1'],
    ['1-4'],
    ['1-8'],
    ['1-0']
])
df['operation_on_b'] = pd.DataFrame([
    ['4-4'],
    ['4-6'],
    ['4-2'],
    ['4-8']
])
```

and obtain result as follows using **pandas only**:

[image]

In numpy I found there is the triu_indices approach but I need to do this on the whole data table to obtain information from other columns.

Could you show me a way to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rsub.html):

```
out = df.rsub(df.iloc[0])
```

or:

```
out = df.iloc[0] - df
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  0  0
1 -3 -2
2 -7  2
3  1 -4
```

If you also need the string representation of the operations:

```
df.iloc[0].astype(str)+'-'+df.astype(str)
```

output:

```
     a    b
0  1-1  4-4
1  1-4  4-6
2  1-8  4-2
3  1-0  4-8
```

Comment: the output seem to be inverted, could you show me how to get the exact value for the operation?

Comment: @Sean my bad, I misread

Comment: thank you very much it worked. Also my bad I only need the numerical result could you please remove the text part so that it is easier for other members to see your solution?

Comment: I remove the last bit but leave the second part, it's still interesting as it's the same concept but with strings

Answer (score 1):

about last part :

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x)
```

Comment: It is however inefficient and useless to loop when you can use a vectorial solution… About 15x slower with `apply` on 200 columns